# I want to show the dicom picture by vtk.When I use the same code in vmware ubuntu and windows，linux does not have result， but windows have

Tags: python, vtk

I want to show the dicom picture by vtk.When I use the same code in vmware ubuntu and windows，linux does not have result， but windows have

this is my code.

```
self.pg_tra = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor()
self.pg_tra_image_viewer = vtkImageViewer2()
self.pg_tra_image_viewer.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
self.pg_tra_image_viewer.SetRenderWindow(self.pg_tra.GetRenderWindow())
self.pg_tra_image_viewer.SetupInteractor(self.pg_tra)
self.pg_tra_image_viewer.SetSlice(int(self.data_Dimensions[2] / 2))     
self.pg_tra_image_viewer.GetRenderer().ResetCamera()
self.pg_tra_image_viewer.Render()
```